# Check emali validation as soon as I move to the next text field

Tags: ios, swift

I have a text field for `UserEmailId`. Below this `UserEmailId` I have  other text fields. I don't want to validate the Email ID after clicking on signup button, I want to check validation as soon as I click on enter and move to next text field.

I only know how to do the validation after all the fields are filled up. Please suggest how to validate as soon as I move to next text field after entering the email address.

```
@IBOutlet weak var emailText: UITextField!

@IBAction func logIn(sender: AnyObject)
{    
    let validLogin = isValidEmail(emailText.text)    
    if validLogin
        println("User entered valid input")    
    else     
        println("Invalid email address")    
}

func isValidEmail(testStr:String) -> Bool 
{    
    let emailRegEx = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,64}"    
    let range = testStr.rangeOfString(emailRegEx, options:.RegularExpressionSearch)    
    let result = range != nil ? true : false    
    return result
}
```

Comment: You can Textfield's didEndEditingMethod to detect if user has moved to next Textfield or ended editing a Textfield and can validate the entered text in this method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume you have two text fields. One for Email address and another for password. Set the tag of `emailTextField` to 0 and the tag of `passwordTextField` to 1. Now what you want to do is validate right after the textfield ends editing. The below code should point you in the right direction. Add `UITextFieldDelegate` to your class and don't forget to set the delegates of your textfield to self.

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if textField.tag == 0{
        if isValidEmail(testStr:textField.text!){
            //Do your stuff
        }
        else{
            //Do something else
        }
    }
    else if textField.tag == 1{
        // Do your other validation
    }
}
```

Comment: @Samjhana I don't understand what you mean by "use delegate instead of tag". How can you use a delegate to identify a textfield? Also, you can just connect the delegates of the textfield that you want to validate.

Comment: Yes, you can compare the outlet instance. Like `textField == emailTextField` instead of `textField.tag == 0`

Answer (score 2):

The best way is add the Validation Methods in the following Delegate methods  `func textFieldShouldEndEditing(UITextField)`   &    `func textFieldDidEndEditing(UITextField)`    add the if conditions in  the delegate method to check which text field is editing and then add the validation

are you got the point or i will add coding samples here

Comment: @Samjhana  here the Sample     //MARK:- Text Field Delegate methods   `func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        if textField == text1 {
            print("Text 1")
        }
        else if textField == text2{
            print("Text 2")
        }
        else{
            print("Text 3")
        }
        
    }`

Answer (score -1):

Email check function return true or false

```
func isValidEmail(text : String) -> Bool {
        let emailRegEx = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,64}"

        let emailTest = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx)
        return emailTest.evaluate(with: text)
    }
```

TextFields Delegate

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if textField == txtEmail{
        if self.isValidEmail(text:textField.text ?? ""){
            //Valid Email
        }
        else{
            //Invalid Email
        }
    }

}
```